# Swift React Native Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter callback

Tags: swift, react-native

I am getting the following error: Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter 'callback'.  I only get this error when I add the callback function. If I remove the callback function this error disappear.

```
 @objc
  func getOffers(_ callback: RCTResponseSenderBlock) {
    Purchases.shared.getOfferings { (offerings, error) in
      /// - If we have an error fetching offerings here, we'll print it out. You'll want to handle this case by either retrying, or letting your users know offerings weren't able to be fetched.
      if let error = error {
          print(error.localizedDescription)
      }
      
      self.offering = offerings?.current
      
      callback([offerings?.current])
    }
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adds `@escaping`. Like this:

```
@objc
  func getOffers(_ callback: @escaping RCTResponseSenderBlock) {
    Purchases.shared.getOfferings { (offerings, error) in
      /// - If we have an error fetching offerings here, we'll print it out. You'll want to handle this case by either retrying, or letting your users know offerings weren't able to be fetched.
      if let error = error {
          print(error.localizedDescription)
      }
      
      self.offering = offerings?.current
      
      callback([offerings?.current])
    }
  }
```